# Scheme - A function that returns T/F if each element of a list is a list of two elements

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a function that returns T/F in regards to if a a list contains elements that are list(s) with exactly two elements which can be any expressions. I am pretty new to Scheme and have been stuck on how to determine how  to go about doing this. I have tried everything from using if, cond, and lambda with no success. It seems I am having trouble figuring out how to have Scheme traverse through the entire list and returning whether it is T/F at the end.

Some examples of what I am looking for:

```
(foobar? '((a 1)(b 2)))
#t
(foobar? '((foo 100)(bar 2 3)))
#f
(foobar? '((a 1) b (c 3)))
#f
(foobar? '((a 1) . 2))
#f
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write a function `has-two-elements?` that determines whether a single list has exactly two elements. That shouldn't be too hard.
2. Write a recursive function `all-have-two-elements?` that determines whether all elements of a list are lists of exactly two elements. There are two cases to consider:

   - Base case: an empty list has no elements that do not have exactly two elements (since it's doesn't have any elements). So, you return `#t`.
   - Recursion: `(has-two-elements? (car l))` and `(all-have-two-elements? (cdr l))` must both be true.

That's seven lines of code if you indent properly.

Comment: So going off with what you said so far (I will continue updating as I figure things out):

`(define (check-length? l) (if (eq? (length l) 2) #t #f))`

Comment: `(define (all-have-two-elements? l)
 (if (null? l) #t)
 ;; recursion`

Not sure I'm understanding how you are describing how to do the recursion part. If the base case returns true for an empty list, then you want me to call the has-two-elements for the first element of the list?

Comment: @user1032208: observe first that `(if (eq? (length l) 2) #t #f)` is equivalent to `(eq? (length l) 2)`. As for the recursion, look up an example of a recursive function on lists in your textbook and study it's structure, maybe copy its skeleton. You're getting close.

Comment: @user1032208: oh, and please use `=` instead of `eq?` for numerical equality.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Here's what I have after some more picking around at it:

`(define (has-two-elements? l) ((= (length l) 2)))`

`(define ((all-have-two-elements? l)
 (cond ((null? l))
       ((and(check-length? (car l)) (zipper? (cdr l))))
    (else #f)
 )
)`

I started testing cases and it seemed to work fine until I passed through a list like such: ((a 1) b (c 3)) in which it complained about b not being a "proper list". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That's far too many parentheses even for a Scheme program :) You can't call `length` on something that is not a list, so put a check for list-ness in `has-two-elements?`.

Comment: I am having another issue now where:
> (all-have-two-elements? '((a 1) . 2))
car: expects argument of type <pair>; given 2

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @user1032208: if this answer was helpful, then please click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

My Scheme is a little rusty, but it seems like solving the following problem is what you really need to do: given something, return its length if it's a list, zero otherwise. Getting the length of a list is easy: if empty, zero; else, 1 + length of tail. Checking whether the thing is a list should somehow be possible, too. Call a function that does this LengthIfList.

Now, your solution is this: true if LengthOfList on the head is 2 and the function applied to the tail returns true or the list is empty, false otherwise.